# Need features Like optgroup in drop down or list box

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, listbox

I want to show content in category and sub category in drop down or list box.

Example  of content

```
 Mobile
  Nokia
  IPhone
  LG
 Laptop
  Dell
  HP
  HCL
```

in this example mobile and laptop is category and rest are sub category.
I want that user can't select category but it will show.
User only select sub category.

Please help me to find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Question is a little unclear but if you are looking for markup, try

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Mobile">
    <option>Nokia</option>
    <option>IPhone</option>
    <option>LG</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Laptop">
    <option>Dell</option>
    <option>HP</option>
    <option>HCL</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

to achieve this in asp.net, [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx) explains how to modify the MVC's `DropDownList` implementation.

Comment: Have added a link to [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/raduenuca/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extending-the-dropdownlist-to-show-the-items-grouped-by-a-category.aspx) that breaks down how to do this in asp.net